# How to load image from Images.xcassets into a UIImage with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have an image from the `Images.xcassets` folder and I want to load it into a `UIImage` programmatically using swift. How can I do this? Anyone done this before? Please give me some code examples!

Comment: let img : UIImage = UIImage(named: "here is the name of the image from Images.xcassets");

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Apple")
}
```

I created an image view and displayed an image inside it.

Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a 'standard' color xcassets item and load it via:

```
UIColor(named: "--asset--name--here--")
```