# Use of unresolved identifier 'WeekOne'

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I am building an array that will display images in a UITableView. When I try to call the image in the array it doesn't find the asset. What am I doing wrong?

We've tried renaming all of the variables / arrays.

```
var videos: [Video] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor .darkmodeGray
}

func createArray() -> [Video] {

    var tempVideos: [Video] = []

    let video1 = Video(image: WeekOne, title: "StoryOne")
    let video2 = Video(image: UIImage, title: "StoryTwo")
    let video3 = Video(image: WeekThree, title: "StoryThree")
    let video4 = Video(image: WeekFour, title: "StoryFour")
    let video5 = Video(image: WeekFive, title: "StoryFive")
    let video6 = Video(image: WeekSix, title: "StorySix")

    tempVideos.append(video1)
    tempVideos.append(video2)
    tempVideos.append(video3)
    tempVideos.append(video4)
    tempVideos.append(video5)
    tempVideos.append(video6)

    return tempVideos

}


// IN A SEPERATE FILE

import Foundation
import UIKit

class Video {

    var image: UIImage
    var title: String

    init(image: UIImage, title: String)    {
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Two different errors based on the text after image:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'WeekOne'

and

> Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage.Type' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

Comment: Why did you expect it to work? What is `WeekOne`, `WeekThree` etc? Can you show their declarations?

Comment: Those are the names of the image files in the assets. They are .png files.

Comment: You can't just use their names directly. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152197/how-to-load-image-from-images-xcassets-into-a-uiimage-with-swift/32152965) answer your question?

Comment: Also, `UIImage` is the name of a data type rather than a variable, which is why you get the 2nd error.

Comment: I am using this code in a separate swift file. I thought it would take the image and put it into the cell in my tableview.

I looked at your link but wasn't able to figure out where/what I need to add to my code. 

class StoryCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var storyImageView:
        UIImageView!

}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, then here's what you are looking for.

```
let video1 = Video(image: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "WeekOne"), title: "StoryOne")
```

You need to your the above initializer of **UIImage** to access an image added to Assets.

The above line of code will be translated to this by your Xcode.

[image]

> let video2 = Video(image: UIImage, title: "StoryTwo")

If **'UIImage'** is an image name, I'd kindly suggest you change it as it may lead to ambiguity. I guess you made a typo there. You typed **UIImage** instead of **WeekTwo**

Also, make sure that you have added corresponding images (WeekOne, WeekTwo, WeekThree, WeekFour, WeekFive, WeekSix) to **Assets**

Answer (score 0):

To really answer this we'd need to see what `WeekOne` is.  The error suggests that you haven't defined `WeekOne`.  The issue with that error lies there.

The second error is a typo in your Video 2 line.  You have UIImage (a class) when you want a variable name instead.

```
let video1 = Video(image: WeekOne, title: "StoryOne")
let video2 = Video(image: UIImage, title: "StoryTwo")
```

Additionally, convention is to make make variable names start with a lower-case letter and all class names start with uppercase letters.  WeekOne, WeekTwo, etc would more properly named weekOne, weekTwo, etc.  This makes it easier to see at a glance what kind of thing each name is.